# getnonfreefonts install problem in TexLive 2017

Tags: fonts, texlive-2017

I'm trying to install the fonts from the package `getnonfreefonts` in TeXLive 2017 (in Manjaro Linux). As in previous TeXLive editions, I do the following:

```
wget http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
cd /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/
sudo ./getnonfreefonts --sys --all
```

However, I get these error messages for each font (I copied just for one of them):

```
========================
Package 'vntex-nonfree':
========================

Downloading 'http://vntex.sf.net/fonts/nonfree/vntex-nonfree-3.1.3.zip'
--2017-06-25 07:39:55--  http://vntex.sf.net/fonts/nonfree/vntex-nonfree-3.1.3.zip
Resolving vntex.sf.net... 216.34.181.96
Connecting to vntex.sf.net|216.34.181.96|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://vntex.sourceforge.net/fonts/nonfree/vntex-nonfree-3.1.3.zip [following]
--2017-06-25 07:39:56--  http://vntex.sourceforge.net/fonts/nonfree/vntex-nonfree-3.1.3.zip
Resolving vntex.sourceforge.net... 216.34.181.96
Reusing existing connection to vntex.sf.net:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 755380 (738K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘vntex-nonfree-3.1.3.zip’

vntex-nonfree-3.1.3 100%[==================>] 737.68K   395KB/s    in 1.9s    

2017-06-25 07:40:03 (395 KB/s) - ‘vntex-nonfree-3.1.3.zip’ saved [755380/755380]
                                                                [download done]

Checking integrity of file 'vntex-nonfree-3.1.3.zip'...                [failed]
File 'vntex-nonfree-3.1.3.zip' seems to be broken.  Please try again.
```

I tried using other CTAN mirrors but it didn't work.
Anyone experienced similar problems with `getnonfreefonts`?

Comment: Try `-v` and/or `-d` to get more information (for verbose and/or debug output).

Comment: Note that the current `install-getnonfreefonts` script is identical to the version available in 2015. Although it differs from the 2013/2014 version, despite claiming to be a version from 2013.

Comment: It works for me. I had one older version and two fonts not installed at all and installation completed with no errors. (I then had to move the updmap.cfg lines as it always puts them in the YYYY tree and I want them in the local tree, where the fonts are!)

Comment: I didn't do it with root privileges, of course. I'm not *that* mad. (Admittedly everyone else *is* that mad.)

Answer (score 2):

Following `cfr`'s suggestion, I used both `-d` and `-v` options. I noticed that the installer was looking for the `unzip` program, which wasn't installed in my Linux box.

```
Checking integrity of file 'garamondx.tds.zip'...
Can't exec "unzip": No such file or directory at ./getfont.pl line 628, <DATA> line 36.
```

That is how the script checks for integrity. However, the normal output does not report that `unzip` is missing. After installing it, everything works smoothly.

Comment: You might want to report that to the maintainers. Though this is the first time I've seen a Linux that did not include unzip out of the box. Then again, I've never heard of that Linux flavor

Comment: Yeap, you're right. (Manjaro is an Arch-based distro.)